# The more precisely - An Adverb Phrase? And its function?

Tags: syntax, parts-of-speech, functions

I am reading **Kane and Abel** by **Jeffrey Archer** where I found the following sentence:

> He spat into the fire, **the more precisely** *to express his opinion of the child's parentage*.

Is **"the more precisely"** an Adverb Phrase? And what is its function? Is it to modify the non-finite infinitive clause - *"to express his opinion of the child's parentage"*.

And the structure of the Adverb Phrase? Is it - the head (*precisely*) and modifier, a Determinative Phrase (*the more*)?

Answer (score 1):

It's a somewhat archaic adverbial phrase, modifying *to express**. Most modern English speakers would probably say:

> He spat into the fire to more precisely express his opinion of the child's parentage.

Nowadays this kind of syntax is rarely used outside of literature, with only *the better to* notably surviving in COCA - likely due to the iconic exchange from Little Red Riding Hood:

> - But Grandmother! What big teeth you have!
>
> - The better to eat you with, my dear!

* The use in LRRH seems to me to suggest that it modifies the infinitive on its own (*to eat you better with them*, rather than *to eat you with them better*), but I don't have a good source for that.

Comment: the more [adverb] to, is not necessarily archaic, which is a very strong word.

Comment: It sounds slightly fancy or old-fashioned, but it's definitely still in use and widely understood.